# selon le vs selon les

Tags: usage, expressions-idiomatiques, accord

Are all sentences below correct? If so, is there a difference in meaning between the two sentences of each pair?

Example 1:

- Selon la culture, la politesse peut prendre différentes formes.
- Selon les cultures, la politesse peut prendre différentes formes
  (= Depending on the culture, politeness can take on different forms)

Example 2:

- Selon le cas, la bourse d'étude peut varier
- Selon les cas, la bourse d'étude peut varier
  (= Depending on the case, the scholarship may vary)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both the singular and the plural are equally possible, without any difference in meaning.

The plural looks to be more popular and that is also the case with its synonym *suivant* which was more common before the sixties.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Juste pour un petit bémol à ajouter à la contribution de @jlliagre :

**Cela dépend quand même un peu du substantif**. Certains sont plus usuels dans un certain sens au singulier et dans un autre sens au pluriel.

Ainsi avec *culture*, le singulier est plus usuel dans le sens de somme de connaissances et le pluriel plus usuel au sens de production agricole.

Ainsi je dirais plus volontiers :

*- Selon la culture, la politesse...*

Mais :

*- Selon les cultures, la charge de travail de...*

**Il y a surtout le cas où on va énoncer une fonction d'une variable** et où l'accord avec la fonction devra primer :

*- Selon **la** fréquence, **le** son est plus ou moins aigu.*

et

*- Selon **les** fréquences, **les** sons sont plus ou moins aigus.*

Ce cas est aisément discernable au fait que l'on peut remplacer l'article défini par un adjectif possessif (*selon **sa** fréquence, le son est...*)